# (closed) How to get the autocomplete query in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Recently, I came to know about the Autocomplete feature in `discord.js@13.6.0` and I wanted to try it out. I was able to do the basics by seeing the answer on this post => [How to use AutoComplete in Discord.js v13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841130/how-to-use-autocomplete-in-discord-js-v13)

I was able to set up the autocomplete and was also able to respond to the autocomplete interaction by using:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
   if (interaction.isAutocomplete()) {
      interaction.respond([
         {
            name: 'Command Help',
            value: 'help'
         }
      ]);      
   }
})
```

But my doubt is that is there any way to get the string which the user typed which caused the autocomplete interaction. For example: there is an array of options, and based on what the user typed, I would be able to filter the options and then show the correct ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do so very easily by using

```js
interaction.options.getFocused()
```

this will return whatever the user is currently typing but if you do

```js
interaction.options.getFocused(true)
```

it will return an object with the the `name` of the option and the `value` that the user has typed so far.

You can find the documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getFocused)