# Different choices for each guild slash command using discord js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am building a discord bot that is going to be used on multiple guilds (a.k.a servers). The bot has a command called 'send' that has a set of **choices** inside an option:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {

    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('send')
        .setDescription('Do stuff')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('choices') // setting the choices
                .setDescription('users will chose one of the options bellow')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoice('choice1', 'potato')
                .addChoice('choice2', 'tomato')
                .setRequired(true))
        

    async execute(interaction) {

       //do stuff

        }; }};
```

All of the other application commands are global, but this specific command must have **custom choices** for each different guild. All this choices are stored on a mongo db, with the respective guild id.

The DB querying is ok to do, but I'm struggling with finding a solution to 'deploy' automatically this commands with different choices for each server. This is my goal with this question, to find a solution to deploy the commands with different choices for each guild.

If needed, I can provide my deploy-commands.js code ( it follows [this tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#registering-slash-commands) ) and also more detail.

Appreciate the help

Comment: You can use different `rest.put` for each server with different commands. There can't be different choices on one command file.

Comment: Isn't it possible to pass the choices as a parameter of the builder or something like that ? @Neenhila

Comment: No, because you're posting choices to server. Ofc you can post one by one but probably you'll get api rate limit. Edit: Also there's time between posting server and server's apply for guilds about 1-2min.

Comment: @p-destri you might want to look into using autocomplete instead of choices for this. Autocomplete works mostly like choices, but is more dynamic and can be updated as input updates. You could query the database for the choices you need within the autocomplete interaction, and return it to the user as autocomplete choices. That's the best you're going to be able to do. Choices themselves cannot be made different for different guilds.

Comment: @Cannicide I'm trying to build it with autocomplete, following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841130/how-to-use-autocomplete-in-discord-js-v13 but I can't fetch the autocomplete options. 

Could you provide an example ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can't fetch the autocomplete options." You might want to open a new Stack question for issues you encounter while trying to setup autocomplete, since that is different from this question and involves different code.

Comment: Please add your deploy code to your question since the commands can be modified in that file as well, please make sure that your data base connection ` const db = require('whatever')` is at the top and (at least for me since I use MySQL rather than mongoos) put how you query that database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the comments, using choices with data from the DB is not possible. The workaround is to use the 'autocomplete' option.

To do that, inside the builder, we add a  `.setAutocomplete(true)` . Now, we need to handle the autocomplete interaction, and fill it with the values that we want form the Database.

It is important to 'filter' the type of interaction that we are handling. Using if statements, we need to verify if the interaction is an **autocomplete** or a **command**. Below is the resulting code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
    const mongo = require('../structures/mongo')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('send')
        .setDescription('items list')
        .addStringOption((option) =>
            option
                .setName('items')
                .setDescription('Select your item from the list')
                .setRequired(true)
                .setAutocomplete(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {

        const guildID = interaction.member.guild.id;
        //query DB for the options 

        let guild = await mongo.getGuild(guildID)

        //loop through guild token and set to autocomplete 

        for (let i = 0; i < guild.guild_tokens.length; i++) {
            choices.push({
                name: `${guild.guild_tokens[i].name}`,
                value: `${i}`,
            })
            tokens.push(`${guild.guild_tokens[i].name}`)
        }

        if (interaction.isAutocomplete()) {
            interaction.respond(choices)
                .catch(console.error);
        }

        // Must handle interactions (command ones) inside the if statement
        if (interaction.isCommand()) {

           //  do stuff 

    }
};
```

On a side note, I had an issue with the interactions at first, because on my 'interactionCreate' file I was returning if the interaction was not a command. It's also important to change that file to not return if the interaction is an 'autocomplete' type:

module.exports = {
name: "interactionCreate",
async execute(interaction) {

```
    if (!(interaction.isCommand() || (interaction.type == 'APPLICATION_COMMAND_AUTOCOMPLETE'))) {
        console.log('fuck')
        return;

    }

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);


    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction)

    } catch (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);

    }
}
```

}