# discord.js v14 AutoComplete does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, autocomplete, discord.js

I'm following the [discord.js Autocomplete guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/autocomplete.html#responding-to-autocomplete-interactions) and have it working well enough when my autocomplete response gives the `name` and `value` as the `id` option, as below:

```js
const choices = [
    {
        id: "5Ut5pguaQnF@DbNF4*nzZX^Rxt4qDYpu^iWZ!CT@g^p7", text: "nice name (5Ut5pguaQnF@DbNF4*nzZX^Rxt4qDYpu^iWZ!CT@g^p7)"
    }, {
        id: "urQ!M*cUvudvmXvJjq6M%fjaZi%Pj5wKdAjzeP*m33q", text: "diff name (urQ!M*cUvudvmXvJjq6M%fjaZi%Pj5wKdAjzeP*m33q)"
    }];

const filtered = choices.filter(choice => choice.text.toLowerCase().includes(focusedValue.toLowerCase()));

await interaction.respond(
    filtered.map(choice => ({ name: choice.id, value: choice.id }))
);
```

I would rather the autocomplete show a nice name instead of just the id, so when I change the `interaction.respond` argument to be:

```js
            filtered.map(choice => ({ name: choice.text, value: choice.id }))
```

in order to make the autocomplete options include more information (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71597193/1486966) and as documented [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/AutocompleteInteraction?scrollTo=respond)), it shows the nice name but autocompletes the nice name, which doesn't work for the option that is being autocompleted.

Image demonstrating:

[image]

after selecting the top result:

[image]

I expect that selection an autocomplete item above will autofill the id into the slash command below, but that doesn't happen.

Edit: Adding my `SlashCommandBuilder` because it might be relevant:

```js
new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('monitor_node')
        .setDescription('Register a new validator node to monitor')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('id')
                .setDescription('The Node ID to monitor')
                .setRequired(true)
                .setMaxLength(44)
                .setMinLength(44)
                .setAutocomplete(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('name')
                .setDescription('A friendly name for the node')),
```

Comment: Maybe try logging the focused text on autocomplete to see what you're filtering for?

Comment: I don't know how to fix this but I want to tell you that AutoComplete is not easy, it is very difficult and also the coding of the AutoComplete is never small, it is big. I mean the code is big. I will advice you to learn how AutoComplete works, how the Discord sends data and also how the discord.js works with the data and also related to these stuffs as well, learn it first.

Comment: I asked on the [discord-api-docs github](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/5749), and it looks like it might be a UI bug. When I turn off min/max length and send the nice `name`, the `value` is ultimately what gets passed back to the `SlashCommand` handler.